# How add named element to R vector with name from a variable

Tags: r, elementname

I want to add an element, say 100, to vector V and use the value of variable x as the new element's name.  I know it can be done like this:

```
V = c(V, 100)
names(V)[length(V)] = x
```

but I'm looking for an easy single-line solution, if there is one.  I tried:

```
V = c(V, as.name(x)=100)
```

and

```
V = c(V, eval(x)=100)
```

but those don't work.

Okay, discovered best way:

```
V[x] = 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ronak Shah's answer worked well, but then I discovered an even simpler way:

V[x] <- 100

I'm going to post a new related and very similar question - How to define an R vector where some names are in variables.

Answer (score 5):

We can do this by using `setnames`

```
setNames(c(V, 100), c(names(V), x))
```

Adding an example,

```
V <- c(a = 1, b=2)
V
#a b 
#1 2 
x <- "c"
setNames(c(V, 100), c(names(V), x))
# a   b   c 
# 1   2 100
```

Or as @thelatemail suggested we could only work on the additional element

```
c(V, setNames(100,x))
```

Comment: potentially simpler - `c(V, setNames(100,x))`